# Change background image in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

So I have set a background image to a button and it works however when I want to change the image to other system image
play.circle all it does is remove the pause.circle backgroundImage and shows nothing.

I am clearly missing something...

```
(sender as! UIButton).setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "play.circle"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

got it working by

```
(sender as! UIButton).setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.circle"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

Comment: means setBackgroundImage is not updating your button image?

Comment: make sure that the image file with correct name (check spelling) is present. Always write unit tests for your resources presence and make sure to run these tests before release.

Comment: The issue was I was using named not system